# 'app-element' is not a known element angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use selector of contact-form component in contact-me component but it gives the error " 'app-contact-form' is not a known element"? My code is as follows:

contact-me.module.ts

```
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
        import { ContactMeComponent } from './contact-me.component';
        import { ContactFormComponent } from './contact-form/contact-form.component';
        import { ContactFormModule } from './contact-form/contact-form.module';


       @NgModule({
            declarations: [ContactMeComponent, ContactFormComponent],
            imports: [
               CommonModule,
               ContactFormModule
            ],
            exports: [ContactMeComponent, ContactFormComponent]
         })
         export class ContactMeModule { }
```

contact-form.module.ts

```
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
        import { ContactFormComponent } from './contact-form.component';
        import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';



        @NgModule({
           declarations: [ContactFormComponent],
           imports: [
            CommonModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule
          ],
           exports: [ContactFormComponent]
        })
         export class ContactFormModule { }
```

contact-me.component.html

```
         <app-contact-form></app-contact-form>
```

contact-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-form',
  templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-form.component.scss']
})
export class ContactFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  contactForm = new FormGroup({
    projectTitle: new FormControl(''),
    fullName: new FormControl(''),
    emailAddress: new FormControl(''),
    phoneNumber: new FormControl('')
  });

}
```

contact-me is one of the routes in app module.

This is my console error:

ERROR in src/app/contact-me/contact-me.component.html:1:4 - error NG8001: 'app-contact-form' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-contact-form' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-contact-form' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

1    
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/contact-me/contact-me.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './contact-me.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ContactMeComponent.

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

What else is needed or what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add code of contact-form.component ts file?

Comment: In your contact-form.module.ts, add ContactFormComponent as entryComponent too.

Comment: @AnkurChauhan what are you talking about?
it has nothing to do with entryComponent....

Comment: @GouravGarg, i have added code for contact-form.component.ts

Comment: @AnkurChauhan, adding ContactFormComponent as entryComponent to contact-form.module.ts did'nt work.

Comment: remove ContactFormComponent from declaration and export of ContactMeModule

Comment: @VishalDeep your `ContactFormComponent` is part of two modules as i can see from the above code. It should be part of only on module and then that module should be imported in any other module where the ContactFormComponent is required. Remove `ContactFormComponent` from  `declarations` and `exports` of ContactModule.

Comment: @GouravGarg, removing ContactFormComponent from declaration and export of ContactMeModule did'nt work.

Comment: @Manish, I have already removed ContactFormComponent from declarations and exports of ContactMeModule as told by Gourav Garg.

Comment: @VishalDeep will it possible for you to create a demo using stackblitz. Will be able to help you better

Comment: @Manish, surely i can do that, wait for 5-10 minutes.

Comment: @Manish, its working fine in stackblitz

Comment: OK then may be you need to go back and check what you are doing differently in your code... will help you fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `ContactFormComponent` from both `declarations` and `exports` in `contact-me.module.ts`
That's all.

Explanation:

You are using `app-contact-form` which is inside `contact-form.module.ts`. So you have to export it from there in order to use it in another module.

and then, import `ContactFormModule` wherever you need `ContactFormComponent`. Here in your case import in `contact-me.module.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Try and make sure the component which you are adding in html template, should be added to app.module.ts. This can directly added or in your case can be added in shared module which is then added in app.module.ts

Comment: You mean to say that i should add ContactFormModule in imports of app.module.ts?

Comment: Yes, Whatever the components you are declaring in your angular app, must be a part of app.module.ts file in one way or another.

Comment: I have added ContactFormModule in imports of app.module.ts, but still it does'nt work.

Comment: Whenever you are making use of Shared Module, try to export the components, providers from that module. It will then be available to app.module which can be used throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the missing part, i needed to import ContactMeComponent in imports of app.module.ts.

Comment: thats not solution. however you may import ContactMeModule in App.module.ts